# Php mysql user rating & comment system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the below given script for star rating. It is working fine but when i want to use $_GET variable in the processing file it is not taking it.

Also i want to use the comments with this script but i can not use $_POST or $_GET in `tuto-star-rating.php`.

I can get `$_GET['sid']` in `index.php` but i can not get sid in `tuto-start-rating.php`. This `tuto-start-rating.php` is called through JS .

In index.php the url is `index.php?sid=1`

In `tuto-star-rating.php` i want to save the restaurant id using $_GET but unable to do that. I tried as below but it is not accepting it is only accepting the number putting directly as you can see in the file code below:

```
$getRest    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sid']);
$query = $bdd->execute('INSERT INTO rest_rating (sr_id, media, rate, ip, user) 
VALUES ('.$getRest.', '.$mediaId.', "'.$rate.'", "'.$ipaddress.'", "'.$user.'")'); // We insert the new rate
```

I need help to integrate comment system with this code using a different form or by integrating in the same.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include('comment/dbClass.php');
    $bdd = new db();
?>
<style>
    .no_star { display: inline-block; background: url("comment/star.png") no-repeat; width: 16px; height: 16px }
    .star { display: inline-block; background: url("comment/star.png") no-repeat; background-position: 0 -16px; width: 16px; height: 16px }
    .star_hover { display: inline-block; background: url("comment/star.png") no-repeat; background-position: 0 -32px; width: 16px; height: 16px }
    .star_selected { display: inline-block; background: url("comment/star.png") no-repeat; background-position: 0 -48px; width: 16px; height: 16px }
</style>
<?php
function starBar($numStar, $mediaId, $starWidth) { // function with arguments: number of stars, media ID, width of the star image
    global $bdd;

    $getRest    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sid']);

    $cookie_name = 'tcRatingSystem'.$mediaId; // Set up the cookie name

    // We get the rate average and number of rate from the database
    $query = $bdd->getOne('SELECT round(avg(rate), 2) AS average, count(rate) AS nbrRate, sr_id AS sr_id FROM rest_rating WHERE media='.$mediaId.' and sr_id = "'.$getRest.'"');
    $avgCeil = round($query['average'], 0); // round above or below to show how many selected stars we display

    $getJSON = array('numStar' => $numStar, 'mediaId' => $mediaId); // We create a JSON with the number of stars and the media ID
    $getJSON = json_encode($getJSON);

    // We create the DIV block with selected stars and unselected stars depending of the rate
    $starBar = '<div id="'.$mediaId.'">';
    $starBar .= '<div class="';
    if( !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) $starBar .= 'star_bar';
    $starBar .= '" rel='.$getJSON.' style="width:'.($numStar*$starWidth).'px">';

    for ($i=1; $i<=$numStar; $i++) {
$starBar .= '<div class="';
if ($i <= $avgCeil) $starBar .= 'star_selected'; else $starBar .= 'star';
$starBar .= '"></div>';
    }
    $starBar .= '</div>';
    $starBar .= '<div class="resultMedia'.$mediaId.'" style="font-size: small; color: grey">'; // We show the rate score and number of rates
    if ($query['nbrRate'] == 0) $starBar .= 'Not rated yet';
    else $starBar .= 'Rating: ' . $query['average'] . '/' . $numStar . ' (' . $query['nbrRate'] . ' votes)';
    $starBar .= '</div>';
    $starBar .= '<div class="box'.$mediaId.'"></div>'; // Return the text "Thank you for rating" when someone rate
    $starBar .= '</div>';

    return $starBar;
}

echo starBar(5, 59, 16); // We create star bar  
?>
```

**tuto-start-rating.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
include('dbClass.php');
$bdd = new db();
    //$getRest  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sid']);
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $user      = session_id();

if($_POST) {                    

    $mediaId = $_POST['mediaId']; // Media ID
    $rate = $_POST['rate']; // Your rate

    $expire = 24*3600; // 1 day
    setcookie('tcRatingSystem'.$mediaId, 'voted', time() + $expire, '/'); // Place a cookie

    $query = $bdd->execute('INSERT INTO rest_rating (sr_id, media, rate, ip, user) 
        VALUES (1, '.$mediaId.', "'.$rate.'", "'.$ipaddress.'", "'.$user.'")
        '); // We insert the new rate

    // We calculate the new average and new number of rate
    $result = $bdd->getOne('SELECT round(avg(rate), 2) AS average, count(rate) AS nbrRate FROM rest_rating WHERE media='.$mediaId.'');

    $avgCeil = round($result['average'], 0); // Round the average

    // Send JSON back with the new average, the number of rate and rounded average
    $dataBack = array('avg' => $result['average'], 'nbrRate' => $result['nbrRate'], 'avgCeil' => $avgCeil);
    $dataBack = json_encode($dataBack);

    echo $dataBack;
}
?>
```

**tuto-star-rating.js**

```
    function rateMedia(mediaId, rate, numStar) {
        $('.box' + mediaId).html('<img src="comment/loader-small.gif" alt="" />'); // Display a processing icon
        var data = {mediaId: mediaId, rate: rate}; // Create JSON which will be send via Ajax

        $.ajax({ // JQuery Ajax
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'comment/tuto-star-rating.php', // URL to the PHP file which will insert new value in the database
            data: data, // We send the data string
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.box' + mediaId).html('<div style="font-size: small; color: green">Thank you for rating</div>'); // Return "Thank you for rating"
                // We update the rating score and number of rates
                $('.resultMedia' + mediaId).html('<div style="font-size: small; color: grey">Rating: ' + data.avg + '/' + numStar + ' (' + data.nbrRate + ' votes)</div>');

                // We recalculate the star bar with new selected stars and unselected stars
                var ratingBar = '';
                for ( var i = 1; i <= numStar; i++ ) {
                    ratingBar += '<div class="';
                    if (i <= data.avgCeil) ratingBar += 'star_selected'; else ratingBar += 'star';
                    ratingBar += '"></div>';
                }

                $('#' + mediaId + ' .star_bar').html(ratingBar).off('mouseenter');
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#box').text('Problem');
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.star_bar').on('mouseenter', function overBar(event) { // Mouse enter the star bar
            var relData = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('rel')); // Get JSON values: number of stars and media ID

            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');

            // We create a new star bar OVER the previous one with transparent stars
            var newStarBar = '';
            for ( var i = 1; i <= relData.numStar; i++ ) {
                newStarBar += '<div class="no_star" id="' + i + '" title="' + i + '/' + relData.numStar + '" onclick="rateMedia(' + relData.mediaId + ', ' + i + ', ' + relData.numStar + '); return false;"></div>';
            }
            $(this).css('position', 'relative').append('<div id="over' + relData.mediaId + '" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">' + newStarBar + '</div>');

            // When we move the mouse over the new transparent star bar they become blue
            $('#over' + relData.mediaId + ' > div').mouseover(function() {
                var myRate = $(this).attr('id');
                for ( var i = 1; i <= relData.numStar; i++ ) {
                    if (i <= myRate) $('#over' + relData.mediaId + ' #' + i).attr('class', 'star_hover');
                    else $('#over' + relData.mediaId + ' #' + i).attr('class', 'no_star');
                }
            });
        });

        // Mouse leaves the star bar, we remove the rating bar
        $('.star_bar').on('mouseleave', function overBar(event) {
            var relData = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('rel'));
            $('#over' + relData.mediaId).remove();
        });
    });

**tuto-star-rating.php**
<?php
    session_start();
include('dbClass.php');
$bdd = new db();
    //$getRest  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sid']);
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $user      = session_id();

if($_POST) {                    

    $mediaId = $_POST['mediaId']; // Media ID
    $rate = $_POST['rate']; // Your rate

    $expire = 24*3600; // 1 day
    setcookie('tcRatingSystem'.$mediaId, 'voted', time() + $expire, '/'); // Place a cookie

    $query = $bdd->execute('INSERT INTO rest_rating (sr_id, media, rate, ip, user) 
        VALUES (1, '.$mediaId.', "'.$rate.'", "'.$ipaddress.'", "'.$user.'")
        '); // We insert the new rate

    // We calculate the new average and new number of rate
    $result = $bdd->getOne('SELECT round(avg(rate), 2) AS average, count(rate) AS nbrRate FROM rest_rating WHERE media='.$mediaId.'');

    $avgCeil = round($result['average'], 0); // Round the average

    // Send JSON back with the new average, the number of rate and rounded average
    $dataBack = array('avg' => $result['average'], 'nbrRate' => $result['nbrRate'], 'avgCeil' => $avgCeil);
    $dataBack = json_encode($dataBack);

    echo $dataBack;
}
?>
```

**dbClass.php**

```
<?php
class db {
    private $conn;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $baseName;
    private $port;
    private $Debug;

    function __construct($params=array()) {
        $this->conn = false;
        $this->host = 'localhost'; //hostname
        $this->user = 'root'; //username
        $this->password = ''; //password
        $this->baseName = 'lepetit'; //name of your database
        $this->port = '3306';
        $this->debug = true;
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
    }

    function connect() {
        if (!$this->conn) {
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password); 
            mysql_select_db($this->baseName, $this->conn); 
            mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this->conn);

            if (!$this->conn) {
                $this->status_fatal = true;
                echo 'Connection BDD failed';
                die();
            } 
            else {
                $this->status_fatal = false;
            }
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if ($this->conn) {
            @pg_close($this->conn);
        }
    }

    function getOne($query) { // getOne function: when you need to select only 1 line in the database
        $cnx = $this->conn;
        if (!$cnx || $this->status_fatal) {
            echo 'GetOne -> Connection BDD failed';
            die();
        }

        $cur = @mysql_query($query, $cnx);

        if ($cur == FALSE) {        
            $errorMessage = @pg_last_error($cnx);
            $this->handleError($query, $errorMessage);
        } 
        else {
            $this->Error=FALSE;
            $this->BadQuery="";
            $tmp = mysql_fetch_array($cur, MYSQL_ASSOC);

            $return = $tmp;
        }

        @mysql_free_result($cur);
        return $return;
    }

    function getAll($query) { // getAll function: when you need to select more than 1 line in the database
        $cnx = $this->conn;
        if (!$cnx || $this->status_fatal) {
            echo 'GetAll -> Connection BDD failed';
            die();
        }

        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $cur = mysql_query($query);
        $return = array();

        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($cur)) { 
            array_push($return, $data);
        } 

        return $return;
    }

    function execute($query,$use_slave=false) { // execute function: to use INSERT or UPDATE
        $cnx = $this->conn;
        if (!$cnx||$this->status_fatal) {
            return null;
        }

        $cur = @mysql_query($query, $cnx);

        if ($cur == FALSE) {
            $ErrorMessage = @mysql_last_error($cnx);
            $this->handleError($query, $ErrorMessage);
        }
        else {
            $this->Error=FALSE;
            $this->BadQuery="";
            $this->NumRows = mysql_affected_rows();
            return;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($cur);
    }

    function handleError($query, $str_erreur) {
        $this->Error = TRUE;
        $this->BadQuery = $query;
        if ($this->Debug) {
            echo "Query : ".$query."<br>";
            echo "Error : ".$str_erreur."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how you are getting $_GET['sid'] in "tuto-start-rating.php" as your ajax is POST type also "sid" is not in data from ajax

Comment: @Farhan well in `index.php` i can get because $_GET is direct here. But in `tuto-start-rating.php` i am unable to get probably here i will get through JS but i am unable to configure in JS.

Comment: From where you're planning to get *sid* value in *index.php* page?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I can get sid in `index.php` but i can not get sid in `tuto-start-rating.php`. This `tuto-start-rating.php` is called through JS

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul please check i replied i can not

Comment: @RajdeepPaul please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539636/php-mysql-user-rating-system-issues-with-rating-different-restaurants) another question as you know this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537771/php-mysql-user-rating-comment-system/39538654#comment66390996_39537771),

> I can get sid in index.php but i can not get sid in tuto-start-rating.php. This tuto-start-rating.php is called through JS

Since you're including JavaScript as an external file, you cannot use/access a PHP variable like `$_GET['sid']` in your *tuto-star-rating.js* file. Your need to change your *index.php* and *tuto-star-rating.js* files in the following way,

**index.php**

Just before you include *tuto-star-rating.js* file in *index.php* page, add this below line,

```
<script>var sid = "<?php echo $_GET['sid']; ?>";</script>
// include your tuto-star-rating.js file
```

**tuto-star-rating.js**

You need to change your AJAX request in the following way,

```
function rateMedia(mediaId, rate, numStar) {

    // your code

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'comment/tuto-star-rating.php?sid=' + sid,

        // your code
    });
}
```

In this way, you can access *sid* in *tuto-star-rating.php* page using `$_GET`
superglobal, like this:

```
$getRest  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sid']);
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: i can not even by this way i was trying but fail

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini In what way you're getting this *sid* value in *index.php* page? Also, explain what you changed in the code and how did it go for you.

Comment: Well please check the index.php in my question its there how i am getting. in index.php the url is `index.php?sid=1` or watever........ and as u said i changed in my js file same way as u said `url: 'comment/tuto-star-rating.php?sid=' + <?php echo $_GET['sid']; ?>,`

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini I've updated my answer. Now it should work fine for you.

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini It's working fine for me. Did you make all the changes I suggested above? Paste the complete *index.php* and *tuto-star-rating.js* code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: yes sorry its working without mysql_real_escape_string what i can use instead of this to secure?? what if there is something else regarding this script can i ask you here or ?

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini `mysql_real_escape_string()` won't prevent your code from SQL injection. As I suggested, start using `mysqli` or `pdo`, and always *prepare*, *bind* and *execute* your queries to prevent any kind of SQL injection.

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini If your *other* question requires a proper explanation with a code fix, then I would suggest you to draft a separate question and ask.

Comment: i will make another question now ok?

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini Sure, go ahead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the $_GET['sid'] first make sure the *sid* is passing in url *(ex: http ://youdomainname.com/?sid=1)*.
Then, pass the *sid* as a parameter to the ***starBar*** function as you can see bellow:

```
function starBar($numStar, $mediaId, $starWidth, $sid) {
    // your code here
}
```

When you call the function (in the final of *index.php* file) don't forget to pass the new parameter:

```
echo starBar(5, 59, 16, $_GET['sid']);
```